# How to create an object out of the 'preProcess' function in R?

Tags: r

I'd like to know how to create an object out of the preProcess function (from the 'caret' package).

The following code isn't creating any object and I don't understand why :

```
function(dt1, dt2, norm = "spatialSign"){
X<-dt1[ ,-ncol(dt1)]
Y<-dt1[ ,ncol(dt1)]
t<-holdout(Y, ratio = 8/10, mode = "random")
prepr<-preProcess(X[t$tr, ], method = norm)}
```

I would like to obtain a prepr object at the end of the function call.

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More information on functions you can find [here](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Writing-your-own-functions), because this is a very basic question.

But for now, there are multiple solutions depending on how you want to call your function.

1. define your function

`my_func <- function(dt1, dt2, norm = "spatialSign"){
  X <- dt1[ , -ncol(dt1)]
  Y <- dt1[ , ncol(dt1)]
  t <- holdOut(Y, ratio = 8/10, mode = "random")
  prepr <- preProcess(X[t$tr, ], method = norm)
}`

Then call your function and store it in an object

```
my_outcome <- my_func(dt1, dt1)
```

2. assign the local prepr variable to a global variable with the `<<-` operator

`my_func <- function(dt1, dt2, norm = "spatialSign"){
          X <- dt1[ , -ncol(dt1)]
          Y <- dt1[ , ncol(dt1)]
          t <- holdOut(Y, ratio = 8/10, mode = "random")
          prepr <<- preProcess(X[t$tr, ], method = norm)
}`

and then use the function as is in your code.

`my_func(dt1, dt2)`

But I recommend the first option as it shows more clearly what is going on and if you want to make changes to the function it needs to be done only in one place.